# I cannot import ksoap2 at my class

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have Android Project in which I want to use ksoap2.

I paste the .jar (ksoap2) in my folder libs, then right click on and go ahead to "Add as Library".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r508j.png)

After I sync my gradle, Android Studio update dependencies in file build.gradle, like this:

compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1.jar')

Finally in my class MainActiviy.java I want to type import org.ksoap2.Envelope, the IDE doesn't recognize the class ksoap2.

What is wrong with mi procedure?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to paste .jar in your libs and add this in your build.gradle(app)

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Then Sync.

Comment: Thank so much. I think my build.gradle is correct. Is that:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  dependencies {     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'     })     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'     compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1.jar') }

Is it incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I pasted the .jar file in libs directly in file browser/finder. The correct way is paste the .jar in libs through de Android Studio.

1. In file browser/finder where .jar file it's, right click and copy.
2. In Android Studio, Project tab select "Project" to see complete structure. Then you can see libs folder.
3. Right click on libs folder and go ahead "Paste As Library"

Android Studio creates the correct structure.